# sapui5 TreeTable setSelected from model

Tags: sapui5

I can't find a good method to select a newly added element.

Imagine an ADD button that adds a new table row to the model. This element should be the selected one automatically.

Which has two problems

1. At the time adding the element to the model, the TreeTable control is not updated yet. It does not contain the row yet.
2. The only way I found to make something selected programmatically is via the setSelected(index) method. But the index is the number of the visible row, not a location within the tree. So all I could do is walking through all rows, check their binding and get the index this way.

I can't seem to find a binding either, e.g. bind a /table/rows/0/enabled path to the selected property and hence set the model and it does updated the table automatically.

Any pointers anybody?

Comment: You could try using a factory function; when invoked for the new element mark it as selected. I am not sure whether this would work for nested items - the sample in the SDK did not preserve selection of nested entries after expand/collapse of parent for `table.TreeTable`. The sample for `m.Tree` did do it, but the items there are `ListItemBase` and have `selected` property.